# Query runs in MySQL Workbench but not running in mysql_query() in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

```
select t1.* 
from bbs_product as t1, bbs_category as t2 
where 
(((t1.product_name_de like '%13"%') or 
(t1.sku_number like '%13"%') or 
(t1.description like '%13"%')) and 
((t1.product_name_de like '%Laptoptasche%') or 
(t1.sku_number like '%Laptoptasche%') or 
(t1.description like '%Laptoptasche%')) and 
((t1.product_name_de like '%im%') or 
(t1.sku_number like '%im%') or 
(t1.description like '%im%')) and 
((t1.product_name_de like '%Buchdesign%') or 
(t1.sku_number like '%Buchdesign%') or 
(t1.description like '%Buchdesign%'))) and 
(t1.category_id=t2.id and t2.status=1) and 
t1.status=1 and 
t1.discontinued='no' and 
t1.is_secret='n'
```

Comment: Which error does it produce in `mysql_query`?

Answer (score 4):

```
t1.sku_number like '%13"%') or 
(t1.description like '%13"%')) and
```

You have double quotes in your query text.

Make sure they are properly escaped in the `PHP` string which is the argument to `mysql_query`.